# Adding an option to post editor to show a site disclaimer or message

Tags: posts, customization, custom-field, metabox, child-theme

I was wondering how I would go about adding an option to add a site disclaimer or message for a **published post** in Word Press.

Something like this (Please See Below)
[image]

Which by checking the box will result in it being in the **HEADER** of the site (Please See Below)

[image]

Below I have the HTML code but I am not sure WHERE I would need to input the code so it would result in me being able to have the **option** to check it when **creating and publishing a post.**

```
 *** <div class="main-wrap">

<div class="site_header" style="background-color:;">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="site_text" style="color:; font-size:14px; line-height:14px; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;">SITE</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <div id="main-head" class="main-head">

<div class="wrap"> ***
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're talking about is called [a custom meta box](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/). They can be used to save post specific settings and data. You can create your own meta boxes with the help of [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function.

Here's a quick example. This would go to your (child) theme's `functions.php` file. Alternatively if you want to make the code theme independent, then create [a custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for the code below. The example works in both Classic and Block editors.

```
// Register metabox only for "post" post type
add_action('add_meta_boxes_post', 'my_prefix_register_my_custom_metabox', 10, 1);
function my_prefix_register_my_custom_metabox( $post ) {
    add_meta_box(
        'my-metabox', // id
        esc_html__( 'My Meta Box', 'textdomain' ), // title
        'my_prefix_render_my_custom_metabox', // callback
        'post', // screen - typically post type
        'side', // context - normal, side, advanced
        'high', // priority - high, low
        array() // optional callback args
    );
}

// Callback function that add_meta_box uses to render the contents of the metabox
function my_prefix_render_my_custom_metabox( $post, $callback_args ) {
    $checked = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_checkbox_value', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_custom_metabox_nonce_action_' . $post->ID, 'my_custom_metabox_nonce' );
    ?>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="_my_checkbox_value" value="1" <?php checked( $checked, 1); ?>>
        <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Display disclaimer', 'textdomain' ); ?></span>
    </label>
    <?php
}

// Callback for saving the metabox form fields when the post is saved
// Executes only when saving "post" post type
add_action( 'save_post_post', 'my_prefix_save_my_custom_metabox', 10, 3 );
function my_prefix_save_my_custom_metabox( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if (
        wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ||
        wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )
    ) {
        return;
    }
    if (
        empty( $_POST['my_custom_metabox_nonce'] ) ||
        ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_custom_metabox_nonce'], 'my_custom_metabox_nonce_action_' . $post_id )
    ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['_my_checkbox_value'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_checkbox_value', 1 );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_checkbox_value', 1 );
    }
}
```

You can also add to the same file a helper function which takes care of displaying the disclaimer message.

```
function my_prefix_display_disclaimer() {
    if (
        is_single() &&
        get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_checkbox_value', true )
    ) {
        ?>
        <aside class="disclaimer">
            <p>This is a disclaimer.</p>
        </aside>
        <?php
    }
}
```

You can then either use the helper function directly in some (child) theme template file.

```
<?php my_prefix_display_disclaimer(); ?>
```

Or hook it into an action hook that your theme might provide.

```
// in functions.php or custom plugin file
add_action( 'some_theme_template_action_hook', 'my_prefix_display_disclaimer' );
```

Comment: Hi Antti, I got the box to appear on the right when I click to create a post but it is not appearing on the header of the page when I preview the post. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this. Would you be so kind to inform me on how to make it appear in the header of my page as it looks above in the pic?

Comment: @Nik The exact implementation depends a bit on the theme you're using. But you basically have two options - 1) action hook or 2) edit theme file. If you're using some theme made by someone else, then the first thing you need to do is to create a child theme. 1) if your theme uses action hooks in its header, hook the rendering function to it (last example in my answer). 2) Alternatively copy the file responsible for displaying the header from parent theme to your child theme and add the function to the copied file (2nd last example in my answer).

Comment: More about child themes, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/